how to pull model automatically with container creation?
When trying to access the ollama container from another (node) service in my docker compose setup, I get the following error:

ResponseError: model 'llama3' not found, try pulling it first

I want the setup for the containers to be automatic and don't want to manually connect to the containers and manually pull the models.
Is there a way to load the model of my choice automatically when I create the ollama docker container?
Here is my relevant part of the docker-compose.yml
ollama:
        image: ollama/ollama:latest
        ports:
            - 11434:11434
        volumes:
            - ./ollama/ollama:/root/.ollama
        container_name: ollama
        pull_policy: always
        tty: true
        restart: always


Are you running on linux?you shouls set env variables first.

isn't docker always linux? :D

No,can run on other OS.

yeah, linux then

Use a custom entrypoint script to download the model when a container is launched. The model will be persisted in the volume mount, so this will go quickly with subsequent starts.
version: '3.7'

services:
  ollama:
    image: ollama/ollama:latest
    ports:
        - 11434:11434
    volumes:
        - ./ollama/ollama:/root/.ollama
        - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: ollama
    pull_policy: always
    tty: true
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]

Key changes:

Added an entrypoint.
Added a volume mount for entrypoint.sh.

This is the content of entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Start Ollama in the background.
/bin/ollama serve &
# Record Process ID.
pid=$!

# Pause for Ollama to start.
sleep 5

echo " Retrieve LLAMA3 model..."
ollama pull llama3
echo " Done!"

# Wait for Ollama process to finish.
wait $pid



you are a G. love it.

whole Russian community will pray for u, G

Thats amazing, been looking for this for quite some time

Why pull some data in the entrypoint script? This looks scary, the whole point of docker it to produce isolated, reliable and complete images. What's wrong with running ollama pull as a RUN step in your own dockerfile from this base image (and using build instead of image)?

very nice idea. how does this compare to first running "docker compose up -d ollama" and then "docker compose run -it ollama ollama run llama3" ?

This is what worked for me without needing an additional mount for the entry script.
services:
  ollama:
    container_name: ollama
    pull_policy: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ollama.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: [your local path here]
        target: /root/.ollama
    ports:
      - "11434:11434"
    restart: always

FROM ollama/ollama

# Copy the script to the docker image
COPY ./wait_for_ollama.sh /wait_for_ollama.sh

# Ensure the script is executable
RUN chmod +x /wait_for_ollama.sh

EXPOSE 11434
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/wait_for_ollama.sh"]

Then I used the script provided by @datawookie as wait_for_ollama.sh in the same directory as the dockerfile.
#!/bin/bash

# Start Ollama in the background.
ollama serve &
# Record Process ID.
pid=$!

# Pause for Ollama to start.
sleep 5

echo " Retrieving model..."
ollama pull phi3:medium
echo " Done!"

# Wait for Ollama process to finish.
wait $pid


A sample with python
FROM ollama/ollama

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 install ollama

ADD docker-entrypoint.py /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3","docker-entrypoint.py"]


docker-entrypoint.py

import os
import socket
import subprocess
import time
import ollama

model = os.getenv("OLLAMA_MODEL", "llama3.1")

def wait_for_port(port, timeout=60):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            return False

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            result = sock.connect_ex(("127.0.0.1", port))
            if result == 0:
                print(f"Ollama is running")
                return True

        print(f"Waitting for ollama on port {port}")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        "ollama serve",
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True,
    )
    wait_for_port(11434)

    client = ollama.Client(host="http://localhost:11434")
    
    installed_models = client.list()
    if model not in installed_models:
        print(f"Download model {model}")
        ollama.pull(model)
    print(f"Ollama is ready")
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()


This setup worked for me:
docker-compose.yml
ollama:
  ...
  entrypoint: ["/entrypoint.sh"]
  volumes:
    - ...
    - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
  ...

entrypoint.sh

Make sure to run sudo chmod +x entrypoint.sh

Adapted from @datawookie's script:
#!/bin/bash

# Start Ollama in the background.
/bin/ollama serve &
# Record Process ID.
pid=$!

# Pause for Ollama to start.
sleep 5

echo "Retrieving model (llama3.1)..."
ollama pull llama3.1
echo "Done."

# Wait for Ollama process to finish.
wait $pid

Why this approach?
By pulling the model in the entrypoint script rather than in the Docker image, you avoid large image sizes in your repository, storing the model in a volume instead for better efficiency.
Edit: Actually, when I think more about it, there might be scenarios where it’s worth putting the model into the image. Decide based on your use case.
